# Content overflow with dynamic content

Tags: javascript, dynamic, overflow

I am using a content div to show the result of a recursive problem - 
 
By starting from the number 1 and repeatedly either adding 5 or multiplying by 3, an infinite amount of new numbers can be produced. How would you write a function that, given a number, tries to find a sequence of such additions and multiplications that produce that number? For example, the number 13 could be reached by first multiplying by 3 and then adding 5 twice, whereas the number 15
cannot be reached at all.

I am trying to find the solution and then pass it back reach() function which populates my content div dynamically:

```
<script>
function findTarget(target) {
        function find(start,history) {
            if (start === target) 
                return history;
            else if (start > target) 
                return null;
            else return ((find(start+5,"("+history+"+5)"))||(find(start*3,"("+history+"*3)")));
        }
        return find(1,"1");
    }
    function reach(x) {
       var p=document.createElement('div');
       var result = findTarget(parseInt(x));
       var text = document.createTextNode(result);
       p.appendChild(text);
       p.setAttribute("class","limit");
       document.getElementById('container').appendChild(p);
   }
</script>

<body onLoad="reach(prompt('Enter a target number to reach'));">
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
```

Here is the css for my container and my content div's

```
#container{ max-width:500px; margin:0 auto; width:500px; 
background-color:#63DA85; word-break:break-all; }
.limit{ width:300px; max-width:300px; margin:auto; word-break:break-all;}
```

When I execute this script, I do get the content- but it overflows out of the div - [image]

I am trying to use word-break:break-all; in my css for both container and content div - But this works only if the content string is generated inside the reach function shown below

```
function reach(x) {
       var p=document.createElement('div');
       var text = document.createTextNode("a really long string like pppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppp");
       p.appendChild(text);
       //p.setAttribute("class","limit");
       document.getElementById('container').appendChild(p);
   }
```

But it breaks when content is set as a return value from some other function like findTarget.

How should I solve this -  I don't want to use Jquery - just pure js solution

Answer (score 3):

To do this simply add the following css to your #container

```
word-break: break-all;
```

This allows the line to break between any two letters , see:

http://jsfiddle.net/us8qpvm0/

Comment: I have edited the question. This css rule does not work when I add to the content div dynamically from a return value of a function

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
word-break: break-all;
```

to your #container class in the CSS.